# IF Query in SQL DELETE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-delete

so I got a blog page, where useres can post "articles" and in these articles there is the possibility to write comments. 
I want to create a IF Query in PHP to delete the article, if only a article is there and no comment or if there is a comment delete the article and the comment in the database.

```
$sql = "DELETE beitrag , kommentar 
        FROM beitrag 
        INNER JOIN kommentar 
        WHERE beitrag.beitrag_id= kommentar.beitrag_id 
          and beitrag.beitrag_id=$pid";
```

Currently this is how my DELTE is looking. It only deletes, if there is article and a comment.

Comment: And what's your question? If you want to create something like that "IF query in PHP", what keeps you from doing it?

Comment: I dont know how to do it, or if there is a way to do just edit the sql statement

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off using foreign key indexes with delete restrictions...

Comment: Can't you run 2 queries which the first one deletes the article by it's ```id``` and the second one deletes it's ```comemnts``` where the ```article_id``` equals the ```id``` of the article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `LEFT JOIN` instead. Use proper joining (by using `ON`) and use a prepared statement, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

`LEFT JOIN` with a delete means that you delete from the main table, but if there are matches in the right table (for you, that's the comments), delete those too.

```php
$sql = "DELETE beitrag, kommentar 
        FROM beitrag 
        LEFT JOIN kommentar 
          ON beitrag.beitrag_id= kommentar.beitrag_id 
        WHERE beitrag.beitrag_id = $pid";
```

Though you can set up a foreign key relation on the comments, so that when the article is deleted, the comments gets deleted too (using the `ON DELETE CASCADE` attribute). That way, you just delete the article, and the comments follows.

```sql
ALTER TABLE kommentar 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (beitrag_id) REFERENCES beitrag(beitrag_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then delete the article with a plain deletion query

```php
$sql = "DELETE FROM beitrag WHERE beitrag_id = $pid";
```

Comment: Thank you! LEFT JOIN worked. But as you said, I will set up a foreign key relation!